# What's with the song names in "A Post-Honkai Odyssey 2 (Original Soundtrack)"?

Tags: honkai-impact-3rd

What do the song titles of [A Post-Honkai Odyssey 2 (Original Soundtrack)](https://music.apple.com/us/album/honkai-impact-3rd-a-post-honkai-odyssey-2-original/1610183505) mean?

The ones that aren't "Side Lake", "The Hanged Man", "The Empress", "Void Archives" or "Re:Oracle", since that's just English.

Timido might be Italian for Shy?

Most seem to be anagrams with spaces? Never played the game, so I'm not sure whether the names are related to the places where they're played?

1. Esv Wa  1:18 - Waves
2. Er Pi   1:30 - Pier
3. Timido (Soundtrack)     0:56
4. Anb Ur  1:30 - Urban

> 

6. Ged Han     1:10 - Hanged

> 

8. Fry BeL     1:42 - Belfry
9. Arnb Car    1:25 - Car Barn?
10. Den Gar     1:34 - Garden
11. Essr Emp    1:01 - Empress

> 

13. Ele Wh  1:36 - Wheel?
14. And IsL     1:20 - Island
15. Or Do   1:15 - Door
16. Re Co - Core

> 

18. Enih Luc    1:04
19. Lucheni     1:12